# Telegram channel option missing from Microsoft Bot Framework's channel registration list

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot, botframework

I was trying to deploy a Microsoft bot framework based bot onto telegram.
I am not able to find the option for adding telegram channel.
Here is a quick screenshot. Any clue about the same?

[image]

Comment: is your issue resolved?